# Why electron invoke not provide data to renderer process?

Tags: electron

Electron not provide data to renderer process but provide it in preload

preload.js

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'tintacle', {
        async supportStatus() {
            await ipcRenderer.invoke('supportStatusHandler').then(status => console.log(status)) // here i getting right status
        }
    }
)
```

main.js

```js
let microSipPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let findPath = spawn('powershell.exe', ['get-process microsip | select-object -ExpandProperty Path']); // find MicroSip path
    findPath.stdout.once('data',  (data) => {
        exePath = iconv.decode(data, '866');
        currentSupportStatus = 'online';
        resolve('online')
    })

    findPath.stderr.once('data', (data) => {
        currentSupportStatus = 'offline';
        dialog.showMessageBox({message: 'Запустите MicroSip', type: 'warning', title: 'Warning!'})
        resolve('offline')
    })
})

ipcMain.handle('supportStatusHandler', () => {
    return microSipPromise
})
```

[image]

And on front i get undefined, here is call of preload func

Renderer

```js
window.tintacle.supportStatus().then(status => console.log(status))
```

Comment: Your function Your function `supportStatus` doesn't return anything.

Comment: how i can return value of ipcRenderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the promise in `supportStatus`:

```js
supportStatus: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('supportStatusHandler')
```

Comment: Your answer made a big difference. Could you please share where you found this in the documentations? It will be very helpful.

Comment: @MohammedNagdy It's just how [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) work.